# Remove WCF binding security at runtime in CreateChannel override

Tags: c#, wcf, security

My application calls a WCF service that uses SSL in production but does not use SSL on my local dev machine. So to run in dev, I currently have to update the app.config to use a binding configuration that doesn't have a `security` node.

E.G. Instead of

```
<binding ...>
  <security mode="Transport">
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

I just have

```
<binding ...>
</binding>
```

I'd rather have this set at runtime based on my solution's active build configuration. I'm already setting the `EndpointAddress` and `ClientCredentials` in an override of the `CreateChannel()` method, so I tried also removing the security at that time like this:

```
    protected override IProcessing CreateChannel()
    {
        System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress uri =
            new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.ProcessingService),
                this.Endpoint.Address.Identity, 
                new System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressHeader[0]);

        this.Endpoint.Address = uri;

#if DEV
        WSHttpBinding binding = (WSHttpBinding)this.Endpoint.Binding;
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;   //Disable security for DEV mode
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;

#else
        //set the service credentials
        this.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Username;
        this.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password;
#endif
```

but when I run this in `DEV` mode, I get an exception:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action '...' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.

Do you know why this isn't working?

Comment: Does your endpoint without security is working fine? You can also try to create a new WSHttpBinding object instead of setting with received one.

Comment: Yes, it works properly using the endpoint without security from the app.config. I get the same error using a new `WSHttpBinding`. I want to reuse the existing one to make sure all other configured properties are the same.

Comment: I think the issue you're encountering is that you're trying to modify the binding *after* it's been created, and generally speaking you can't do that.   You'll need to configure the binding first.

Comment: @Tim Is there any way to do that so that it will affect all calls to the service? Configuring the binding in each place the service is used throughout the application won't be feasible.